# Calls to typeinf and typeinf_ext in Julia profiling output

Tags: profiling, julia

I am profiling my Julia code. Significant portion of the time is spent in `typeinf` and `typeinf_ext` (and their callees). Is this a tell of type incertainty or type instability?

Comment: Right now you are picking up compilation time -- try running the code once before profiling to get a more useful result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to Julia lang [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/profile/#basic-usage):

> It’s a good idea to first run the code you intend to profile at least
>   once (unless you want to profile Julia’s JIT-compiler)